# Trying to de-normalize the data with dlpyr

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I have a relatively simple problem that is driving me crazy.

```
means <- tibble(
  Sepal.Length = 5.84,
  Sepal.Width = 3.06,
  Petal.Length = 3.76,
  Petal.Width = 1.20
)

sds <- tibble(
  Sepal.Length = 0.828,
  Sepal.Width = 0.436,
  Petal.Length = 1.77,
  Petal.Width = 0.762
)

centroids_standardized <- tibble(
  `.cluster` = factor(c("Cluster_1", "Cluster_2", "Cluster_3")),
  Sepal.Length = c(-1.01, 1.13, -0.0501),
  Sepal.Width = c(0.850, 0.0881, -0.880),
  Petal.Length = c(-1.30, 0.993, 0.347),
  Petal.Width = c(-1.25, 1.01, 0.281)
)
```

What I want to do now is 'denormalize' the data. Converting the standardized units of the centroids to the original units (before scaling).

I tried the following (seemed reasonable, but it does not work:

```
centroids_original_scale <- centroids_standardized %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x * unlist(sds) + unlist(means)))
```

It gives me this cryptic message:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(where(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width), ~.x *
  unlist(sds) + unlist(means))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while evaluating `where(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)`.
Caused by error in `is_function()`:
! object 'Sepal.Length' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: This task would be much simpler if you just converted your data to long rather than wide format. Then you'd just have to do two left joins and a  single mutate.

Comment: Check the base R option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrating my comment, obviously this is all jammed into a single pipeline, it could be split up into separate steps for readability, and if the data were already in long format much of this code would be unnecessary.

```
centroids_standardized |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-.cluster)) |> 
  left_join(
    pivot_longer(sds,cols = everything(),values_to = 'sd'),
    by = 'name'
  ) |> 
  left_join(
    pivot_longer(means,cols = everything(),values_to = 'mn'),
    by = 'name'
  ) |> 
  mutate(value_std = (value*sd) + mn) |> 
  select(.cluster,name,value_std) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = value_std)
```

Comment: Thanks a million Joran. I wouldn't have thought of that in a million years :-).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Base R:

```
cbind(centroids_standardized[1],
     t(t(centroids_standardized[-1])*unlist(sds) + unlist(means)))

   .cluster Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1 Cluster_1     5.003720    3.430600      1.45900    0.247500
2 Cluster_2     6.775640    3.098412      5.51761    1.969620
3 Cluster_3     5.798517    2.676320      4.37419    1.414122
```